# iPad, Resize custom button in viewForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uibutton

My application has splitview and it's activated only in landscape mode.
In masterview i have tableview and in the last section i have a custom button.
The problem is that the button width stays in potrait instead of using device orientation.
I've tried to play with setAutoresizingMask on button and view but that doesn't work either.

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger) sectionNum {
    if (sectionNum == 4) {
        CGRect frameSize;

        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
            frameSize = CGRectMake(45.0, 0.0, 600.0, 44.0);
        } else {
            frameSize = CGRectMake(45.0, 0.0, 680.0, 44.0);
        }

        UIView *btnView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frameSize] autorelease];

        // button
        UIButton* btnFind = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btnFind setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonblue.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:14.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnFind setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonred.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:14.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        btnFind.frame = frameSize;
        btnFind.tag = 1;

        [btnFind setTitle:@"Find" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnFind addTarget:self action:@selector(doSearchDoc:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        //[btnFind setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];

        //[btnView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
        [btnView addSubview:btnFind];

        return btnView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Can someone please let me know how to resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had other issues that the header was not refreshed when rotating the device, ie. the method above was not invoked in my situatio, you could check if this is the case also for you.
The solution I adopted was to invoke reloadData in the rotating method :

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    // This solves an issue that the header doesn't show when roating device (ok on simulator)
    NSIndexPath* ipselected = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:ipselected animated:false scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
}
```

Of course it is usable if you can afford a full reload when rotating the device but itis typically a time when the user will better accept a 0.5s delay as he/she is busy with moving the device.

lternatively you could keep an ivar to your button and change its frame in the above method.

Comment: in my case this works better: i modified your code and replace .reloadData with .reloadSections: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:btnSectionIndex] withRowAnimation:NO];